# Show the total energy is conserved

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, symmetry

> If the Lagrangian does not depend explicitly on time, then the quantity $E$ given by
>   $$E := p\dot{x} - L \tag{1}$$
>   is conserved.

I'm really confused. Normally the total energy is given by $$E = T + V.\tag{2}$$ Our definition of the $\textbf{Lagrangian}$  is
$$L(x,\dot{x}, t) = T - V\tag{3}$$
with $T$ being the kinetic energy and $V$ being the potential energy. So I think to rearrange to get
$$L = p\dot{x} - E = p\dot{x} - T - V.\tag{4}$$
But I don't know what the kinetic and potential are?

Comment: How do you know that's what $E$ is? If you insert (3) into (1) and assume the usual expressions for $T$ and $p$ you should be able to get some intuition for what is going on here.

Comment: so that gives me $E = p\dot{x} - T + V = p\dot{x} - \frac{p^2}{2m} + V$? I just feel so lost with what to look for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The precise statement is the following:

> Given
>
> 1. the definition of Lagrangian momentum $p_i:=\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^i}$,
> 2. the definition of Lagrangian energy $h:=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i v^i-L $, and
> 3. the Euler-Lagrange eqs. $\frac{dp_i}{dt}\approx \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^i}$,
> 4. the Lagrangian $L(q,v)$ does not depend explicitly on time $t$,
>
> then the Lagrangian energy is conserved $\frac{dh}{dt}\approx 0$.

- For the perspective of Noether's theorem, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451) related Phys.SE question.

Note that:

- A Lagrangian $L$ is not necessarily on the form $T-V$, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50075/2451) Phys.SE post.
- [Mechanical energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_energy) $T+V$ is not necessarily the same as Lagrangian energy.
- OP's Eqs. (2)-(4) do not necessarily hold.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Chapter 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the special case $L=T-V$ with $T=\frac{p^2}{2m},\,p=m\dot{x}$, you can show $p\dot{x}=2T$. The expression you've been given for $E$ is always conserved; you can prove this using an Euler-Lagrange equation.

Comment: Yeah I have the Euler-Lagrange equation $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i}\bigg) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i} = 0$$ But I don't understand how to apply it?

Comment: Take $q=x$, then define $p$ canonically.

Comment: what do you mean by canonically?

Comment: Use canonical momentum, not kinetic momentum, viz. $p=\partial_\dot{q} L$.

Comment: Would that mean that $$p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \Rightarrow L = p\dot{x} \Rightarrow E = p\dot{x} - p\dot{x} = 0$$ so is conserved? Or would it be that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big(p\Big) - 0 = 0 - 0 = 0$$

Comment: No, $E$ isn't $0$ in general. I suggest differentiating $p\dot{x}-E$.

Comment: From what i'm given $$p\dot{x} - E = L \Rightarrow \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = p - E$$

Comment: No, because $\partial_\dot{x}p\ne 0$. If you look up "Beltrami Identity", you'll find the proper calculation.