# Does $L=T-V$ still hold when $L$ is NOT time-dependent?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, time, potential-energy

I am aware that the Lagrangian $L=T-V$ where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $V$ is the potential energy when $L$ depends on, for example, $r, \dot{r}, t$. My question is, does this still hold when the Lagrangian does not explicitly depend on time, i.e. I have $L(r,\dot{r})$ instead?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50075/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.  Indeed most Lagrangians do not depend explicitly on time, v.g. 
for the harmonic oscillator
$$
L(x,\dot{x})=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 - \frac{1}{2}kx^2
$$
doesn't depend explicitly on $t$.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that is the lagrangian does not explicitly depent on time, energy is conserved.

Comment: @Ballanzor actually the Hamiltonian is conserved, which need not always coincide with the energy.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero you are absolutely right, not always the same.