# Non-quadratic kinetic energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, non-linear-systems

Do you have examples of Lagrangians/Hamiltonians used in physics with non-quadratic kinetic terms? e.g. $\dot{x}^4$ 
What is the origin and the interpretation of such terms?

Comment: I feel like this has been asked before, but searching for it is coming up empty.

Comment: I did search for duplicates, but without luck.

Comment: Check out https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50075/2451